# How do you display and validate to custom format using Dijit DateTextBox?

Tags: javascript, date, dojo, dijit.form

I want to change the display format of the date for dijit dateTextBox.
Currently my date is displaying like this

[image]

My declaration is like this

```
<input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-attach-point="theInput"  />
```

But I would like to change the format to any format I want for example September 14, 2017, or 09-14-2017.

Also if entering the format using keyboard, is it possible to validate against that same format - I.e. when user types in the data it has to be in that format or the invalid message appears.

**EDIT**:
All I could find was mention of the constraints which allows you to set both the input constraints and formatting - but there are no examples in the documentation how to use this.  It would be nice to see both declarative and programmatic example.

[image]

Also according to some other posts here in declarative markup you can specify constraints like

```
data-dojo-props="constraints:{datePattern:'yyyy-MM'}"
```

However I want to do this programmatically but when I inspect the input object

```
this.theInput.constraints
```

there is no such property as datePattern, or min and max.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible for both programmatic and declarative code :

1. **for declarative example :**

just put your pattern , min , max in the constraints props like :

```
<input type="text" name="shortYear" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="constraints:{datePattern: 'MM-dd-yyyy',min:'2016-12', max:'2018-06'}" value="09-14-2017" required="true" />
```

See working fiddle

```js
require(["dijit/form/DateTextBox","dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Button","dojo/on" ,
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(DateTextBox,parser,Button, On ) {
  parser.parse();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<body class="claro">
<input type="text" name="shortYear" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="constraints:{datePattern: 'MM-dd-yyyy',min:'2017-09-03', max:'2018-01-01'}" value="09-14-2017" required="true" />
</body>
```

Or this [FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/4nknnhb5/)

2. **for programatic example :**

you've just to use to access directly the constraints object and set your constraint value there`Mydateinput.constraints.contName = value` like

```
myDateBox.constraints.datePattern  = 'MM-dd-yyyy'
myDateBox.constraints.min = new Date();
myDateBox.constraints.max = new Date("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

See working snippet

```js
require(["dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dijit/form/Button","dojo/on" ,
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(DateTextBox,Button, On ) {
  datebox = new DateTextBox({
    }, "date");
    datebox.constraints.datePattern = 'MM-dd-yyyy';
    
    datebox.constraints.min = new Date("2017/09/03");
    datebox.constraints.max = new Date("2018/01/01")
    
    datebox.startup();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="date" ></div>
</body>
```

Or the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/1Ld17szr/)